# Unable to Isolate Transactions Across Tiers in Postgres / JDBC

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

I'm working on a Java project that incorporates a **PostgresSQL 9.0** database tier, using **JDBC**.  SQL is wrapped in functions, executed in **Java** like stored procedures using JDBC.

The database requires a *header-detail* scheme, with detail records requiring the foreign-key ID to the header.  Thus, the header row is written first, then a couple thousand detail records.  *I need to prevent the user from accessing the header until the details have completed writing.*

You may suggest wrapping the entire transaction so that the header record cannot be committed until the detail records have completed writing.  However, you can see below that I've isolated the transactions to calls in Java:  write header, then loop thru details (while writing detail rows).  Due the the sheer size of the data, it is not feasible to pass the detailed data to the function to perform one transaction.

**My question is:  how do I wrap the transaction at the JDBC level, so that the header is not committed until the detail records have finished writing?**

The best solution metaphor would be SQL Server's named transaction's, where the transaction could be started in the data-access layer code (outside other transactions), and completed in a later DB call.

The following (simplified) code executes without error, but doesn't resolve the isolation problem:

```
DatabaseManager mgr = DatabaseManager.getInstance();
Connection conn = mgr.getConnection();
CallableStatement proc = null;

conn.setAutoCommit(false);
proc = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN TRANSACTION");
proc.execute();

//Write header details
writeHeader(....);
for(Fault fault : faultList) {
    writeFault(fault, buno, rsmTime, dnld, faultType, verbose);
}
proc = conn.prepareCall("COMMIT TRANSACTION");
proc.execute();
```

Your brilliant answer will be much appreciated!

Comment: What about `DatabaseManager`?

Comment: Why don't you share the connection (and transaction) on `writeHeader` and on the `writeFault` loop?

Comment: I don't see anything about your code which does not resolve the isolation problem.  Where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry guys, I had a hidden conn.setAutoCommit(true);  Problem solved!  Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the same connection for writeHeader and writeFault?

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

headerProc = conn.prepareCall("headerProc...");
headerProc.setString(...);
headerProc.execute();

detailProc = conn.prepareCall("detailProc...");

for(Fault fault : faultList) {
    detailProc.setString(...);
    detailProc.execute();
    detailProc.clearParameters();
}

conn.commit();
```

And then you should really look at "addBatch" for that detail loop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Glenn.  While I did find that my mistake was a hidden auto-commit, your answer was going to be what I'd try next.

Answer (score 2):

While it seems you've solved your immediate issue, you may want to look into JTA if you're running inside a Java EE container. JTA combined with EJB3.1* lets you do declarative transaction control and greatly simplifies transaction management in my experience.

*Don't worry, EJB3.1 is much simpler and cleaner and less horrid than prior EJB specs.

Comment: Thanks, Craig, will do. It sounds like JTA transactions are recommended over other transaction APIs. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709864/use-jta-transaction-or-not